# How to delete user from multiple projects in team project collection of TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Am getting error while deleting user from contributor list of multiple projects in a team project collection of TFS 2013 by using

**tfssecurity /g- groupIdentity memberIdentity [/collection:CollectionURL] [/server:ServerURL]**

Error: Multiple identities found matching 'contributors'. please specify the following identities

I want to delete the user from all the projects of collection at a time.

can anyone advise me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add the project name, this should do the trick:

```
tfssecurity /g- “[Team Project Name]\Contributors” n:Datum1\jpeoples /server:http://ADatumCorporation:8080
```

Comment: Do I need to run the above command for each project or I can specify the multiple project names in single query. If yes can you please mention the query for multiple team projects in a collection

Comment: Would have to be each project but you could script it to iterate through all team projects with a little work

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** delete the user in all projects **with a single query**.

Example: if you get the list of groups for user like, Member of 4 group(s):

- [G] Domain\TFS_Developers
- [A] [Team Project1]\Contributors
- [A] [Team Project2]\Contributors
- [A] [Team Project3]\Contributors

You need to specify the detail project such as *Team Project3* with below command:

```
 [tfssecurity /g- /collection:http://[servername]:8080/tfs/[CollectionName] [Team Project3]\Contributors n:[user ID]]
```

More detail info you can refer [this blog](http://www.aymanzaza.com/2012/01/18/remove-user-security-pesmissions-from-tfs-2010/).

Comment: Isn't this identical to my answer?